# Is there a common family of weight functions for which the center is zero?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, weighted-regression

One interesting formulation of the ordinary least squares model coefficient is as a weighted average slope where the weights are given by the squared differences between the $X$ values.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i \ne j} w_{ij} \frac{Y_i - Y_j}{X_i - X_j}}{\sum_{i \ne j }w_{ij}} \\
w_{ij} = (X_i - X_j)^2
\end{array}
$$

I was wondering if you can create a generalized weighted average slope regression model by specifying a general class of weights $w^*$ that satisfy only $w_{ii} = 0$. I noticed that in smoothed density estimation, there is already a body of work on the types of weight functions to evaluate similar distances.